# Сместить элементы к центру GridLayoutManager /RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Необходимо сжать элементы у второго ряда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRandom = new Random();

        mCircleRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.circle_recycler_view);
        mCircleRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


        mAdapter = new CircleAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        final GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 12);//Количество столбцов в сетке

        gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {

                switch (position % 7) {

                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                        return 3;
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                    case 6:

                        return 4 ;
                }
                return 3;
            }
        });

       mCircleRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);


        mCircleRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 40; i++) {
            mAdapter.addItem(R.drawable.belarus);
        }


    }
}
```

**Разметка item:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main_activity:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/circle_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: А зачем `position % 7`?

Comment: @Flippy
для расположения элементов в нужном мне порядке , т.е номер позиции делится и возвращается остаток ,А потом я возвращаю 4 элемента,А потом 3 элемента

Comment: @Flippy что подразумевается под сжать? Убрать пространство между картинками?

Comment: @Аксенов Владимир, не я задал вопрос

Comment: Прошу прощения. @upward что подразумевается под сжать? Убрать пространство между картинками?

Comment: @Аксенов Владимир
на скрине видно область,которую нужно убрать